# How to assign height and width to anchor tag link

Tags: html, css

I have tried as the following

```
<div class="tag">
 <a href="#">Book Form</a>
</div>
```

in css

```
.tag a 
{ 
  background-color:#899898;
  height:125px;
  width:250px;
  color:#000;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

The issue is that height and width of anchor doesn't change. Please help me

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` in the css.

```
<div class="tag">
 <a href="#">Book Form</a>
</div>
```

in css

```
.tag a 
  { 
  display: inline-block;      
  background-color:#899898;
  height:125px;
  width:250px;
  color:#000;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:25px;
  }
```

---

Anchor (`<a>`) are inline elements. ([here](http://www.tutorialchip.com/tutorials/inline-elements-list-whats-new-in-html5/) is a complete list of elements that are inline by default). Inline elements can't have `width` and `height`. So if you want `inline` elements to maintain it's native property, i.e. be in the normal flow of line, and still have *width*, *height* and *vertical-align* properties.. then `inline-block` is the property you should be using.

#### Relevant Links

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display
  *

**Edit**: added explanation

Comment: Would be a better answer if you explained why

Comment: Sure... I'll add the details bit, no issues at all.

Answer (score 4):

make the anchor have a style of either `display:inline-block` or `display:block`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

In order for a tags to have dimensions they must be `display: block`

So your css should be:

```
.tag a {
  display: block;
}
```

I tend to avoid inline-block, as I personally find it inconsistent when solving problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Give a style to anchor of `display:block` and `max-width:30px !important;`
max-width size can be any

`li a {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    max-width: 30px !important;
}`